# Android app, google cloud and data store / mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, google-app-engine

I am developing an android app that using google cloud endpoints at the back end. The google cloud endpoints are REST. and are mapping the operation of get, delete, update and insert. So, how can I perform some criteria searches that involve multiple get operation initialize by the client?

How can I manage the end points to work with the database?

I can find not much about this. Any good tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ming, Stack doesn't really allow questions about finding tutorials or something so broad. To get a good question here, normally it is suggested to start working on it, and highlight exactly WHAT is blocking you. Seems like you got a good idea of endpoints. Maybe focus on why you have issues with connecting to the DB, and post a specific question about that? :)

Comment: Hi Patrice, thank you for your advice. I really need a simple example and some key words to start with. I have found something about google cloud datastore. But I cannot find anything to bridge the endpoints and datastore or mysql database.